# how to join value from another table by same condition value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created two tables named "**posts**" with fields **id,post_name** and '**post_meta**' with fields **id,post_id,meta_name,meta_vale**..

Then I've inserted some values like this.

in Post table:-

```
+----+--------------+
| id |  post_name   |
+----+--------------+
| 15 | fsdfsd       |
| 16 | fsdgbfg fsd  |
+----+--------------+
```

in  Post_meta table:-

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | post_id | meta_name | meta_value |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |      15 | image     | image1.jpg |
|  2 |      15 | image     | image2.jpg |
|  3 |      16 | image     | image3.jpg |
|  4 |      15 | image     | image4.jpg |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to create a query to get output like this

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |  post_name  | meta_value  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 15 | fsdfsd      | image1.jpg  |
| 16 | fsdgbfg fsd | image3.jpg  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

Only one meta vale along with it's post_id...

Please help me.

Comment: What ideas do you have to achieve this?

Comment: you have any specific reason why 'image1.jpg' why not 'image4.jpg'??? or any random row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m.id, p.post_name, m.meta_value
from posts p
inner join post_meta m on p.id = m.post_id
inner join 
(
   select post_id, min(id) as minid
   from post_meta
   group by post_id
) m2 on m.post_id = m2.post_id and m.id = m2.minid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id,a.post_name,b.meta_value 
   FROM posts as a 
   INNER JOIN post_meta a p ON a.id=b.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Post_meta, Post where 
(conditions)
Join Post_meta on Post_meta.Post_id = Post.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT pm.id, p.post_name, pm.meta_value
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_meta pm ON pm.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY pm.id ASC
GROUP BY pm.post_id
```