# How to display a complex recordset in a simple sort-able table structure in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a reporting script, where reports fields are not always fixed. Admin may add/remove/modify fields. I have created below tables for that,

**reports**

```
id  user_id csp_id  date
1       1       1   2018-10-09
2       1       1   2018-10-10
3       2       2   2018-10-09
4       2       2   2018-10-10
```

**reports_meta_fields**

```
meta_id      display_name  type  default_value
csp_address  CSP address   text
csp_name     CSP Name      text
```

**reports_meta_values**

```
report_id   user_id     meta_id         meta_value
1           1           csp_address     Shivmandir
1           1           csp_name        Shiv CSP
2           1           csp_address     Matigara
2           1           csp_name        Mat CSP
3           2           csp_address     Darjeeling
3           2           csp_name        Dar CSP
4           2           csp_address     Gangtok
4           2           csp_name        Gang CSP
```

This is how the date need to be displayed in the frontend, I also need a sorting with date, csp_name etc

```
id  user_id csp_id  date        csp_name    csp_adress
1       1       1   2018-10-09  Shiv CSP    Shivmandir
2       1       1   2018-10-10  Mat CSP     Matigara
3       2       2   2018-10-09  Dar CSP     Darjeeling
4       2       2   2018-10-10  Gang CSP    Gangtok
```

I have tried this sql, but this not what I am looking for

```
SELECT reports.*, reports_meta_values.meta_id, reports_meta_values.meta_value  FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values WHERE reports.id = reports_meta_values.report_id


id  user_id     csp_id      date        meta_id         meta_value
1   1           1           2018-10-09  csp_address     Shivmandir
1   1           1           2018-10-09  csp_name        Shiv CSP
2   1           1           2018-10-10  csp_address     Matigara
2   1           1           2018-10-10  csp_name        Mat CSP
3   2           2           2018-10-09  csp_address     Darjeeling
3   2           2           2018-10-09  csp_name        Dar CSP
4   2           2           2018-10-09  csp_address     Gangtok
4   2           2           2018-10-09  csp_name        Gang CSP
```

I am looking for a suggestion in mysql or in php how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you would have offered an SQL Export of your tables, I would have already posted an answer.  Now I have to bother writing up these tables and data my hand.

Comment: Sorry for bother you, but I found the answer myself, I have used this following query to sort out the issue,

SELECT reports.*, mt1.meta_value AS CSP_NAME, mt2.meta_value AS CSP_ADDRESS
FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values mt1 ON reports.id = mt1.report_id AND mt1.meta_id='csp_name'
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values mt2 ON reports.id = mt2.report_id AND mt2.meta_id='csp_address'
WHERE 1

Comment: How would you like to proceed?  Do you wish to remove your question to recover lost rep points, or do you want to keep the page alive and accept an answer?  If you wish to delete the page, I can withdraw my answer to allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, this should be the sql to display data in proper structure,

```
SELECT reports.*, mt1.meta_value AS CSP_NAME, mt2.meta_value AS CSP_ADDRESS
FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values mt1 ON reports.id = mt1.report_id AND 
mt1.meta_id='csp_name'
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values mt2 ON reports.id = mt2.report_id AND 
mt2.meta_id='csp_address'
WHERE 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a little while to set things up in my database, but you should use two `INNER JOIN`s to differentiate the meta_values, then ORDER BY as desired.

```
SELECT a.*, b.meta_value AS csp_name, c.meta_value AS csp_address
FROM reports a
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values b ON a.id = b.report_id AND b.meta_id = 'csp_name'
INNER JOIN reports_meta_values c ON a.id = c.report_id AND c.meta_id = 'csp_address'
ORDER BY date, csp_name, csp_address
```

[image]

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/38530 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/20066101/2943403